# C++ function runs even if it shouldn't?

Tags: c++, user-defined-functions

I'm new to C++ but I have a good handle on it. I am trying to take a list of names and grades and find the largest. Everything is working except that my function runs every time I check for the highest grade.

```
    //Compares to find highest grade
    void highestTest(studentType info[]){
            int testValue, i;
            testValue = 0;
            i = 0;
            for(i; i < 20; i++){
                if(info[testValue].testScore < info[i].testScore){ 
                    testValue = i;
                }
            }
            //Should run at the very end of the function
            if(i == 20)
                    outPut(testValue, info);
    }

    void outPut(int highTest, studentType info[]){
            cout << "The highest test score goes to " << info[highTest].studentFName << " " << info[highTest].studetnLName << " with a grade of " << info[highTest].testScore << endl;
            cout << "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~Students~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~" << endl;
            for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
                    cout << info[i].studetnLName << ", " << info[i].studentFName << info[i].grade << endl;
            }
    }
```

The rest of the code is as follows, I am aware that this is not the best way to do this but I am not allowed to include anything else in main and we are given specific requirements as to what type of functions are required.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct studentType{
    string studentFName;
    string studetnLName;
    int testScore;
    char grade;
};

void fillArray(studentType info[]);
void labelGrades(studentType info[]);
void  highestTest(studentType info[]);
void outPut(int highTest, studentType info[]);
    string first[20] = {"student", "student", "student", "student", "student", "student", "student", "student", "student", "student", "student", "student", "student", "student", "student", "student", "student", "student", "student", "student"};
    string last[20] = {"student", "student", "student", "student", "student", "student", "student", "student", "student", "student", "student", "student", "student", "student", "student", "student", "student", "student", "student", "student"};
    int grades[20] = {97, 98, 96, 99, 86, 94, 88, 84, 85, 86, 89, 100, 84, 97, 91, 82, 92, 83, 89, 95};
    studentType info[20];

int main() {
    fillArray(info);
    return 0;
}

void fillArray(studentType info[]){
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
        info[i].studentFName = first[i];
        info[i].studetnLName = last[i];
        info[i].testScore = grades[i];
    }
    labelGrades(info);
}

void labelGrades(studentType info[]){
    int i = 0;
    for(i; i < 20; i++){
        if(info[i].testScore >= 90 && info[i].testScore <= 100){
            info[i].grade = 'A';
            highestTest(info);
        }else if(info[i].testScore >= 80 && info[i].testScore <= 89 )
            info[i].grade = 'B';
        else if(info[i].testScore >= 70 && info[i].testScore <= 79 )
            info[i].grade = 'C';
        else if(info[i].testScore >= 60 && info[i].testScore <= 69 )
            info[i].grade = 'D';
        else if(info[i].testScore <= 59)
            info[i].grade = 'F';
        else
            cout << "An error occured please let the developer know" << endl;
    }
}
```

I did change all names (first/last) to student as to not disclose classmates. If anyone has any idea as to why void outPut runs everytime there is an 'A' and any possible fixes that would be great!

Comment: Fixed the code formatting just awaiting peer review

Comment: This will be always true after the loop is done: `for(i; i < 20; i++) ... if(i == 20)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The value of `i` when you exit the for loop `for(i; i < 20; i++){`  will be i == 20.  so the test `if (i == 20)` will always pass and `outPut()` will be called everytime.

Answer (score 2):

This for loop ends when i = 20

```
for(i; i < 20; i++){
    if(info[testValue].testScore < info[i].testScore){ 
        testValue = i;
    }
}
```

and then your next line is an if statement that tests for i == 20, so every time you call this function it will call outPut.